# PHP Function Call Returns Fatal Error

Tags: php

For some reason my PHP function call `<? r(); ?>` returns a fatal error.  Any help?

```
<?php
//$r is previously assigned
function r() {
    echo ( $r );
};
?>

<html>
    <head>
        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="<? r(); ?>rs/css/master.css">
    </head>
```

Comment: Posting the error message might be helpful

Comment: Unless something is turning an E_NOTICE into an Exception, what you've describe isn't sufficient to generate a fatal error. Please post more information about the error you're experiencing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to refer to a global object from inside an object, you need to explicitly declare it as [`global`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php):

```
function r() {
    global $r;
    echo ( $r );
}
```

But in general, referring to global variables in this way is **bad style**.  You should consider passing in prerequisites as function arguments:

```
function r($r) {
     echo ( $r );
}

...

r($r);
```

Comment: bad style still gets the job done and keeps the code short.  props

Answer (score 4):

Defining a function changes the scope, where `$r` won't be inside that function. Try sending in `$r` with the function in this manner:

```
<?php
function r($r) {
    echo ( $r );
}
?>
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="<?php r($r); ?>rs/css/master.css">
```

<sub>or defining `global $r;` at the beginning of the function (not preferred).</sub>

Also, you shouldn't use `<?` to open PHP. If all the function does is echo the value of `$r`, it would make more sense to just do this:

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo ( $r ); ?>rs/css/master.css">
```

Comment: Agreed...except for defining $r as global. ;-)

Comment: @Nilpo: I don't like using global for a simple variable, which is why I more mentioned it as a side-note afterwards. I used my ninja-powers to utilize my grace period and make it smaller. ;)

Comment: Right on.  I definitely agree with you.  Using global variables is almost always a bad practice.  Variables should be explicitly passed between scopes.  Less mistakes, neater code that easier to follow, etc.  I won't say definitively say they don't have their place, but I can only think of a single time I would condone using globals--when defining globally accessible constants.  But even then, I personally resort to other means.